# How to check operational status of AWS Services through the API

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

We need to show the operational status (e.g. running/pause/stopped) of AWS Services without logging in to the AWS account. Please see whether AWS provides some API or something other measures to achieve such goal.

Please let me know the procedure to achieve this.

Comment: Are you talking about status of out of box services provided by AWS? like shown in this [AWS Service Health Dashboard](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) OR you would like to track Health of custom applications deployed on various AWS resources?

Comment: Wanted to track the Health of custom applications deployed on various AWS resources?. Like EC2, S3,Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[AWS SDK's](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) or AWS CLI** for knowing status without logged IN to AWS Console Account .

and also you can use your favorite language for programmking with AWS SDK.

Example- if you are python developer then you can use Use [BOTO3 SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html)..

below is the example for checking your instance status

```
for i in ec2.instances.all():

    if i.state['Name'] == 'stopped':

        i.start()
```

if you are concerned about notifying yourself after status change , then you can use SNS, it sends you email after happening of some events .. you need to subscribe to SNS Topic